# How to find all combinations in column and count occurrences in data

Tags: r, count, combinations

I am trying to find all actual combinations within my data of values in column 1.

I then want to count all occurrences of these by column 2.

It feels like R should be able to do this fairly quickly. I tried reading up on combn and expand.grid, but with no success. The main problem was I could not find any guidance on how to generate combinations within a column.

My data looks like:

```
Animal (n=57) | Person ID (n=1000)
Dog     | 0001
Cat     | 0004
Bird    | 0001
Snake   | 0002 
Spider  | 0002
Cat     | 0003
Dog     | 0004
```

Expected output is:

```
AnimalComb | CountbyID

Cat         | 1
DogBird     | 1
SnakeSpider | 1
CatDog      | 1
```

**EDIT** deleted an erroneous entry for cat

Comment: would you like to explain how u get some of the CountbyID?

Comment: Why do you have two `cat` and how do you get those counts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I have understood you correctly, you need to `group_by` `PersonID` and `paste` the all the `unique` `Animal`s in the group and count the number of occurrence of their combination which can be done counting the number of rows in the group (`n()`) and dividing it by number of distinct values (`n_distinct`).

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(PersonID) %>%
  summarise(AnimalComb = paste(unique(Animal), collapse = ""), 
            CountbyID = n() / n_distinct(Animal)) 

#  PersonID AnimalComb  CountbyID
#     <int> <chr>           <dbl>
#1        1 DogBird             1
#2        2 SnakeSpider         1
#3        3 Cat                 1
#4        4 CatDog              1
```

Answer (score 0):

An option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,  .(AnimalComb = toString(unique(Animal)),
      CountbyID = .N/uniqueN(Animal)), by = PersonID]
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Animal = c("Dog", "Cat", "Bird", "Snake", "Spider", 
"Cat", "Dog"), PersonID = c(1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L)),
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```